# Installed D7 with Minimal profile and root user do not have any role set to it. How to create a locked role for root?

Tags: 7, users

Now I can create only simple role which can be easily edited and deleted. I need a role for root user (user ID 1) for some other modules that requires selecting a role.

Now installing minimal profile of Drupal my root user is roleless. Don't know how to call it.

In overall I need something that the root user would be undeletable/uneditable by any other admin who has power to edit users and permissions and roles.

Comment: make installation with 'standard' profile.

Comment: I know that, but that's not really a solution.

Comment: did u enable User module?

Comment: Well yeah... I don't think you're following me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to `/admin/config/people/accounts#edit-admin-role` and select from the list which role should be treated as "Admin role".